# Nested anonymous namespaces

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

It is legal in C++ to declare nested anonymous namespaces in the following manner:

```
namespace {
    namespace {
        struct Foo
        {
        };
    }
}

namespace {    
    struct Foo // SAME IDENTIFIER AS <unnamed>::<unnamed>::Foo!!!
    {
    };
}
```

However, how would you declare an identifier using an explicitly typed Foo to avoid ambiguity?

EDITED -- for all of you who do not read the question.

p.s. I have no intentions to use this sort of constructs, but I need to understand whether it is possible to disambiguate Foo in case someone finds a legitimate use for it. My compiler extension needs to handle all cases.

Comment: `::Foo` is the second on GCC 4.7.2. I'm not sure how to specify the first, as just `Foo` is ambiguous.

Comment: While the nesting of anonymous namespaces is OK, I think it would be extremely unwise to put multiple identical names into different levels of anonymous namespacing. The anonymous namespace is *intended* to serve as a file-local version of the global namespace, and shouldn't be abused.

Comment: @KerrekSB I need to know if it is possible so my GCC plugin will handle all cases. I have never and have no intentions to do nested namespace in such a way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++ standard states it pretty clearly in 7.3.1.1p1:

> An unnamed-namespace-definition behaves as if it were replaced by

```
inline(opt) namespace unique { /* empty body */ }
using namespace unique ;
namespace unique { namespace-body }
```

> where inline appears if and only if it appears in the
>   unnamed-namespace-definition, all occurrences of unique in a
>   translation unit are replaced by the same identifier, and this
>   identifier differs from all other identifiers in the entire program.

So from above, we know that your code actually translates to the following:

```
namespace unique1 {}
using namespace unique1;
namespace unique1 {
    namespace unique2 {}
    using namespace unique2;
    namespace unique2 {

        struct Foo
        {
        };

    }
}

namespace unique3 {}
using namespace unique3;
namespace unique3 {

    struct Foo
    {
    };

}
```

<s>Therefore, your first `Foo` can **only** be accessed within `namespace unique1` and the second `Foo` can be accessed in the global namespace due to `using namespace unique3;`.</s> I was wrong. Corrected by comments below.

Then from 7.3.4p4:

> For unqualified lookup (3.4.1), the using-directive is transitive: if
>   a scope contains a using-directive that nominates a second namespace
>   that itself contains using-directives, the effect is as if the
>   using-directives from the second namespace also appeared in the first.

Therefore, when you refer to `Foo`, it can mean either `unique1::unique2::Foo` or `unique3::Foo`, which is an **error**. **Note that** the other answer says: `has hidden unique name that cannot be accessed`. This is **incorrect**, they can be accessed due to the using directives, it is just that both names are visible.

**However**, by prepending the scope resolution operator `::` to `Foo` you **can** access `unique3::Foo` because of the following:

From 3.4.3.2p2:

> For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set
>   S(X,m) is defined as follows: Let S0(X,m) be the set of all
>   declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If
>   S0(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S0(X,m); **otherwise, S(X,m) is the
>   union of S(Ni,m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives
>   in X and its inline namespace set**.

The emphasized part says `using-directives in X`, which in your case means `using namespace unique1;` and `using namespace unique3;`, so the namespace-qualified lookup set looks like this: `S(unique3::Foo)`, which means `unique1::unique2::Foo` **is not** included in the set and therefore is not an error.

Comment: But this `namespace {
namespace {
int foo1() { return 0; }
}
int foo2() { return 1; }
}
int foo3() { return 2; }


int main() {
    cout << foo1() << foo2() << foo3() << "\n";
}` produces 012 without problems http://ideone.com/CbeVUu

Comment: @PiotrNycz: Perhaps my understanding of using directives is wrong then. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: The `using` directives places everything in the current namespace. So the next `using` that's one level up will also pull everything that was previously pulled. So everything can be accessed.

Comment: I also think that the second top level namespace name will be unique1, not unique3, from "all occurrences of unique in a translation unit are replaced by the same identifier".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is fully legal, since it does not contradict to anything.

Unnamed namespace is conceptually equivalent to:

```
namespace <09FD8E6E-2DB6-4517-B62D-3B5A657DCC82>
{
  // ....
}
```

Meaning that each unnamed namespace has hidden unique name that cannot be accessed.

Comment: @KerrekSB: No, because the question is "how would you declare an identifier using an explicitly typed Foo to avoid ambiguity?". The first part is more like an assertion given "it is" and not "is it" as well as absence of the question mark...

Comment: @VladLazarenko: Ohh, sorry, misread that! You're absolutely right.

Comment: I counter your point about not being accessible with `namespace { struct Foo{}; } Foo foo;`.

Comment: Unnamed namespaces come with an implicit `using` directive so that their members can be accessed outside the namespace. Therefore, members can be accessed just fine.